# Bootstrap Range Slider limit handle range

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, rangeslider

I replaced the handle of bootstrap slider with a background image of size 39px x 39px.

Now I want to limit the range of my bootstrap slider handle as seen on the second [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jtjrxu3m/1/). 
However, how do I fix it in a way that the handle does not get out of range of the track?

```
<div style="width:80%; margin: 50px auto;">     
    <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='rangeslider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="300" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"/>
</div>
<div style="width:80%; margin: 50px auto;">     
    <input type="range" step="1" value="0" max="10" min="0" name="Size" id="size">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard html5 input with type range. However, you need to [style](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-range-slider-style/) to work with different browsers (so far, only IE works out of the box).

Comment: no, i cant, since i cant style the lower track of my input type range. thats why i need the bootstrap slider.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs the answer:

I switched to Powerange, since the IOS styles of the handle will not overlap the track.